# MATLAB preallocating space to unroll different size matrices from cell arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab, memory

I am trying to allocate space to my for loop but it just won't work.

I have looked at all the similar questions and matlab help and it doesn't make any difference. I must be missing something.

```
xt = [];
yt = [];

for ii = 1:size(result,1)
        x = result{ii,1}(:,1);
          xt = [xt;x];
        y = result{ii,1}(:,2);
          yt = [yt;y];
end
```

And my attempt at precollacting space for xt has been

```
xt = zeros(size(result,1),1);
```

with no results. I think my problem might be that `result` is a cell array??

Comment: What is `x`, a scalar or an array?

Comment: x is an array not scalar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you concatenate you don't need to prealocate. If you prealocate don't concatenate!

```
 xt = [xt;x];
```

The previous line will take `xt`, will put `x` amount of **NEW** values in the end of it, appended. It will not substitute the values of `xt`.

To be able to allocate memory for different sizes of a cell array youll need to know the number of elements of each one.

```
sizes=zeros(size(result,1),1);
for ii=1:size(result,1)
    sizes(ii)=size(result{ii},1);  %//get the size of the matrix
end
%// now we know the sizes

xt=zeros(sum(sizes),1); %the total number is the sum of each of them

%// handle the first special case
xt( 1:sizes(1) )=result{1,1}(:,1);
%// add the rest
for ii = 2:size(result,1)
    xt( 1+sum(sizes(1:ii-1)) : sum(sizes(1:ii)) )= result{ii,1}(:,1);
end
```

Comment: result is <100x1> and matrices inside are  <(changing value) x 2>

Comment: @user3536870 The problem with matlab matrices is, <(changing value)> is not a valid dimension! how would you like to put the data in the short `xt`?

Comment: Just noticed x is infact an array, also the matrices in the cell array all vary in size but all are x2

Comment: @user3536870 the best way to do it then is not preallocating memory.

Comment: But when reading millions of data this will take such a long time right? That was my aim of trying preallocation to speed it up a little

Comment: @user3536870 I dont think the speed up will be that big in this case. Youll need a bit of fancy indexing and another for loop to compute the sizes of <(changing value)> before you prealocate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91180/discussion-between-user3536870-and-ander-biguri).